# Is there a Javascript object notation format leaner than JSON/BSON?

Tags: javascript, json, bson

Are there any good serialization/deserialization format for simple Javascript object trees that have a significantly smaller footprint than JSON does? BSON is not very impressive.

The redundant overhead in JSON is especially significant for trees where many objects share the same set of properties. In theory, it should be possible to detect schemas in object arrays such that the property names are not repeated.

Comment: Have you tried gzipping your JSON?

Comment: @alex - It will eat to much server CPU as the data is not cacheable. I rather generate a compact representation to begin with.

Comment: @PatriciaBrothers In general, gzipping a compiled lib's serialization is significantly faster than building an alternative serialization in script.

Comment: Try using protobuf http://prototypejs.org/, it looks somewhat ugly but once you get to learn how to use it, you will see the benefits, and it works in the most common languages server side 2

Answer (score 2):

You can turn your JSON into more of a "database" format, and then translate it back into regular objects. The result can be worth it at times.

```
// Typed on the fly
var dict = [
  ["FirstName", "LastName"],
  ["Ken",       "Starr"],
  ["Kermit",    "Frog"]
];
```

Then you can loop the dictionary, with something like this:

```
// Again, typed on the fly
var headers = dict[0];
var result = []
var o;
for (var i = 0 + 1; i < dict.length; i++) {
  o = {}
  for (j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
    o[headers[j]] = dict[i][j];
  }
  result.push(o);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gzip is fast. *Very fast.* And I have a good deal of confidence that it's the best (in terms of both practicality and efficiency) solution for lean object transportation.

To illustrate the point, I've built a quick sample on one of my staging sites.

http://staging.svidgen.com/ajax/test-a.js generates 5k rows of simple data and outputs raw, untainted JSON.

```
$data = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 5000; $i++) {
    $data[] = array(
        'value-a' => $i,
        'value-b' => pow($i,2),
        'value-c' => pow($i,3)
    );
}

print json_encode($data);
```

The gzipped response is **65KB** and takes about **357ms** to request, build, serialize, and transmit. Omitting client-size parsing from the equation, that's a *throughput* of **182KB/s**. Considering the **274KB** of raw data transmitted, that's an *effective* throughput of **767KB/s**. The response looks like this:

```
[{"value-a":0,"value-b":0,"value-c":0},{"value-a":1,"value-b":1,"value-c":1} /* etc. */]
```

The alternative format, http://staging.svidgen.com/ajax/test-b.js, generates the same 5k rows of simple data, but restructures the data into a more efficient, indexed JSON serialization.

```
$data = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 5000; $i++) {
    $data[] = array(
        'value-a' => $i,
        'value-b' => pow($i,2),
        'value-c' => pow($i,3)
    );
}

$out_index = array();
$out = array();

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $new_row = array();
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
        if (!isset($out_index[$k])) {
            $out_index[$k] = sizeof($out_index);
        }
        $new_row[$out_index[$k]] = $v;
    }
    $out[] = $new_row;
}

print json_encode(array(
    'index' => $out_index,
    'rows' => $out
));
```

The gzipped response is **59.4KB** and takes about **515ms** to request, build, serialize, and transmit. Omitting client-size parsing from the equation, that's a *throughput* of **115KB/s**. Considering the **128KB** of raw data transmitted, that's an *effective* throughput of **248KB/s**. The response looks like this:

```
{"index":{"value-a":0,"value-b":1,"value-c":2},"rows":[[0,0,0],[1,1,1] /* etc. */ ]}
```

So, in our fairly simple example, the raw, restructured data is over 50% smaller than the original raw data. But, it's only 9% smaller when gzipped. And the cost, in this case, is a 44% increase in total request time.

If you wrote a binary library to restructure the data, I expect you could significantly reduce that 44%. But, it's still highly unlikely to worthwhile. You need it to serialize the data without taking more than a 9% longer than encoding the structure "normally" to see any gain at all.

The only way to avoid the restructuring or "alternative serialization" hit is to work with all your objects server-side in the awkward, indexed manner from start to finish. And, unless you're really pressed to get every negligible ounce of performance out of your hardware, that's really just a terrible idea.

And in both cases, the space savings of gzip well beyond what we're able to accomplish using an alternative JavaScript comptable format.

(And we haven't even taking client-size parsing into account -- which is going to be *very significant* for anything that isn't "normal" JSON or XML.)

### In Conclusion

Just use the built-in serialization libraries and gzip.

Comment: Do your `b`s refer to bits or bytes? Normally you should uppercase it when you refer to bytes.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Sizes are taken from the Chrome network monitor. So, I believe they're in *bytes*.

Comment: @CodesInChaos ... and thanks for pointing out the ambiguity. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Your numbers are pretty low, but without investigating the causes it's hard to get any good conclusions.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I wouldn't take the results as Gospel. But, they *do* illustrate a pretty insignificant memory advantage; which, even without considering the time-cost (avoidable by using the more convoluted format from start to finish) likely renders the effort of a "clever" solution a bad investment. (The widely-assumed and accepted point I'm illustrating is that it's hard to compete with *well-established* binary libraries.)

Answer (score 0):

1. There are really fast compression libraries. So it's not a given that a compact format is better than a less compact format plus compression.

   I don't have a link at hand, but I think a former protobuf designer recommended this approach.
2. Check out [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org). It's a rather compact binary format with semantics pretty similar to JSON or BSON.

   Short arrays (up to 16 elements), maps (up to 16 pairs) and strings (up to 32 bytes) have a single byte overhead. Small integers(-32 to 128) take only a single byte total.

Comment: MessagePack is interesting. But, it's value seems to be more in space-savings on the server-side during caching, logging, etc.. The named big companies that are using it (e.g. Pintrest) still seem to be using standard JSON + gzip for transport. (Per your 1st point, if I understand it correctly.) I could give this answer an upvote if it included some data indicating whether MessagePack tends to yield a higher effective throughput than gzipped JSON.